# How to update value of specific embedded document, inside an array, of a specific document in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have the following structure in my document:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("43jh4j343j4j"), 
  array : [
            { 
              _arrayId : ObjectId("dsd87dsa9d87s9d7"),
              someField : "something",
              someField2 : "something2"
            },
            { 
              _arrayId : ObjectId("sds9a0d9da0d9sa0"),
              someField : "somethingElse",
              someField2 : "somethingElse2"
            }
   ]
 }
```

I want to update **someField** and **someField2** but only for one of the items in the array, the one that matches **_arrayId** (e.g. `_arrayId : ObjectId("dsd87dsa9d87s9d7")`; and only for this document (e.g. `_id : ObjectId("43jh4j343j4j")` ) and no other.

The **arrayIds** are not unique to the document that's why I need it to be for a specific document. I could use the `$ positional operator` if I wanted to update that value within the array for every document it exists in, but that's not what I want.

I am trying to accomplish this in [java](/questions/tagged/java) but a command line solution would work as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could still use `$ positional` operator to accomplish this. But you need to specify the objectid of the parent doc along with the _arrayid filter. The below command line query works fine

```
db.so.update({_id:ObjectId("4e719eb07f1d878c5cf7333c"),
              "array._arrayId":ObjectId("dsd87dsa9d87s9d7")},
              {$set:{"array.$.someField":"updated"}})
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. So the query in `coll.update(query, data)` works like a filter to find the document you are looking for, and as selector to the portion of the document you are interested in?

Answer (score 24):

Here is RameshVel's solution translated to [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
    DB db = conn.getDB( "yourDB" ); 
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection( "yourCollection" );

    ObjectId _id = new ObjectId("4e71b07ff391f2b283be2f95");
    ObjectId arrayId = new ObjectId("4e639a918dca838d4575979c");

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", _id);
    query.put("array._arrayId", arrayId);

    BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
    data.put("array.$.someField", "updated");

    BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
    command.put("$set", data);

    coll.update(query, command);
```

Comment: What if we have one more level of array by creating someField an array as well? Can we write something like  data.put("array.$.someField.$.anotherField", "updated"); Not working for me

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. array.$.field was the trick (I'm using 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

...and this is how to do it with mongo-driver version >= 3.1 (mine is 3.2.2):

```
final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoURIString));
final MongoDatabase blogDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("yourDB");
MongoCollection<Document> postsCollection = blogDatabase.getCollection("yourCollection");

ObjectId _id = new ObjectId("4e71b07ff391f2b283be2f95");
ObjectId arrayId = new ObjectId("4e639a918dca838d4575979c");

Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq( "_id", id ), Filters.eq("array._arrayId", arrayId));
Bson setUpdate = Updates.set("array.$.someField", "updated");
postsCollection.updateOne(postFilter, setUpdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as none of the answers actually explain how to do this a) in Java and b) for multiple fields in a nested array item, here is the solution for mongo-java-driver 3.12.3.

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Updates;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(...);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
collection.updateOne(
    Filters.and(
            Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("43jh4j343j4j")),
            Filters.eq("array._arrayId", new ObjectId("dsd87dsa9d87s9d7"))
    ),
    Updates.combine(
            Updates.set("array.$.someField", "new value 1"),
            Updates.set("array.$.someField2", "new value 2")
    )
);
```

This thread has helped me towards the right solution, but I had to do more research for the full solution, so hoping that someone else will benefit from my answer too.