# C# official MongoDB driver code for updating(replacing) inner array in document in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I ve got situation like described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425993/how-to-update-value-of-specific-embedded-document-inside-an-array-of-a-specifi)

I need some help to write this code using official MongoDb C# driver.

I not only want to update one item from document array but also want to create new one if there is no such item with _arrayId. Also there shouldn't be two array items with the same _arrayId (I have tried to use `AddToSet` but with no luck).

It's a big headache; I hope there is easier way to achieve this.

```
var actionUpdate = Update.Set("Votes.$", vote.ToBsonDocument());
var actionPush = Update.Push("Votes", vote.ToBsonDocument());
var actionPull = Update.Pull("UserId", vote.UserId);

var querySpecific = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(_contentId)), 
    Query.EQ("Votes.UserId", vote.UserId));
var queryPromise = Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(_contentId));

MongoCollection collection = null; 

if (_type == ContentType.Promise)
    collection = DataService.PromiseSet.Collection;

var userVotes = collection.Count(querySpecific);
if (userVotes == 1)
{
    collection.Update(querySpecific, actionUpdate);
}
else if (userVotes == 0)
{
    collection.Update(queryPromise, actionPush);
}
else
{
    collection.Update(queryPromise, actionPull);
    collection.Update(queryPromise, actionPush);
}
```

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an easier way, although it is not that difficult if you consider the amount of effort that this type of update would require in SQL.

As for your followup, the C# driver returns a SafeModeResult (make sure safemode is turned on).  This result will have a DocumentsAffected property in which you can tell to see if the update happened.  If it did not, then you'll want to insert the value into the array.

Comment: I killed an hour with blind kitten experementing with buildinq requests and achived something that works like i want to.
But it looks awful =)
Plz give me good reference to read about using SafeModeResult and review my code if it will not bother you much.

Comment: This seems like a good solution to me.  Regarding the ugliness, I would hope this is sequestered off somewhere where it doesn't get seen that much.  When that's the case, it doesn't matter what it looks like as long as it works.